# Android draw() not triggered

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, drawer

I'm trying to implement Navigation Drawer using Drawer Layout without Action Bar.
Everything went smooth until i figured out that the drawer image didn't animate/slide like YouTube or Google Plus app.

What i meant with drawer image
[image: what i meant with drawer image]

Then i tried to implement my custom DrawerListener. Here is my activity class.

```
    lstMenuDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
            selectMenu(pos);
        }
    });
    drawerToggle = new GRHDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, imvDrawer.getDrawable());
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
```

And here is my listener class

```
  public class GRHDrawerToggle implements DrawerListener {

private Activity mActivity;
private SlideDrawable mSlider;

/** Fraction of its total width by which to offset the toggle drawable. */
private static final float TOGGLE_DRAWABLE_OFFSET = 1 / 3f;

public GRHDrawerToggle(Activity activity, Drawable drawerImage){
    mActivity = activity;

    mSlider = new SlideDrawable(drawerImage);
    mSlider.setOffset(TOGGLE_DRAWABLE_OFFSET);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mSlider.setPosition(0);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSlider.setPosition(1);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float glyphOffset = mSlider.getPosition();
    if (slideOffset > 0.5f) {
        glyphOffset = Math.max(glyphOffset, Math.max(0.f, slideOffset - 0.5f) * 2);
    } else {
        glyphOffset = Math.min(glyphOffset, slideOffset * 2);
    }
    mSlider.setPosition(glyphOffset);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


private class SlideDrawable extends InsetDrawable implements Drawable.Callback {
    private final boolean mHasMirroring = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 18;
    private final Rect mTmpRect = new Rect();

    private float mPosition;
    private float mOffset;

    private SlideDrawable(Drawable wrapped) {
        super(wrapped, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current position along the offset.
     *
     * @param position a value between 0 and 1
     */
    public void setPosition(float position) {
        mPosition = position;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public float getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the maximum offset when the position is at 1.
     *
     * @param offset maximum offset as a fraction of the drawable width,
     *            positive to shift left or negative to shift right.
     * @see #setPosition(float)
     */
    public void setOffset(float offset) {
        mOffset = offset;
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        copyBounds(mTmpRect);
        canvas.save();

        // Layout direction must be obtained from the activity.
        final boolean isLayoutRTL = ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(
                mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
        final int flipRtl = isLayoutRTL ? -1 : 1;
        final int width = mTmpRect.width();

        canvas.translate(-mOffset * width * mPosition * flipRtl, 0);

        // Force auto-mirroring if it's not supported by the platform.
        if (isLayoutRTL && !mHasMirroring) {
            canvas.translate(width, 0);
            canvas.scale(-1, 1);
        }

        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

}

But still no sliding animation in my drawer button.
And then i realized method draw(Canvas canvas) in my listener class was never triggered.
Can someone tell me please where is my errors?

Many thanks.
gellaps